# c++ boost compilation catastrophe

Tags: c++, boost, compilation

I'm writing a DLL plugin for a windows application,
after adding the following includes:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
```

I get a wonderful compilation error:

```
Error 3 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__cdecl' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\locale.h 111 LeverateMetaTraderServerAPI
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone who isn't really smart added this :

```
#define __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall APIENTRY
```

to one of the API .h files your including

Comment: i dont quite understand the reason, but basically yep

Answer (score 4):

I'm no authority on C++, but this sort of thing happens when you miss a ; off the end of your class definition.

Answer (score 2):

This error is (with high probability) not caused by Boost. It's probably either the result of a missing semicolon somewhere else in your code or triggered by a missing header include leaving some macro undefined.